# Adding days to a date in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime, timedelta

I have a date `"10/10/11(m-d-y)"` and I want to add 5 days to it using a Python script. Please consider a general solution that works on the month ends also.

I am using following code:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

StartDate = "10/10/11"

Date = datetime.strptime(StartDate, "%m/%d/%y")
```

`print Date` -> is printing `'2011-10-10 00:00:00'`

Now I want to add 5 days to this date. I used the following code:

```
EndDate = Date.today()+timedelta(days=10)
```

Which returned this error:

```
name 'timedelta' is not defined
```

Comment: General clue: if you get the error `name 'timedelta' is not defined`, that means that you haven't defined `timedelta` anywhere. Python is usually pretty informative about its error messages.

Comment: Search didn't work?  All of these code examples would have helped: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+timedelta.  There appear to be over 200 questions just like this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add days to a date in Python using loops, ranges, and slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206759/add-days-to-a-date-in-python-using-loops-ranges-and-slicing)

Comment: You want to add five days, but then you have timedelta(days=10)…I'm confused about where the 10 came from and why it isn't 5

Comment: with same question, exclude the Weekend means?

Answer (score 938, accepted):

The previous answers are correct but it's generally a better practice to do:

```
import datetime
```

Then you'll have, using [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
date_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, "%m/%d/%y")

end_date = date_1 + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
```

Comment: datetime.datetime - why twice?

Comment: importing like "from datetime import datetime, timedelta" would add readibility to the code

Comment: @paulmorriss: You are calling the `strptime` method on the `datetime` class in the `datetime` module, so you need to specify `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: If explicit is better, u should avoid to short'n it. But, agree with `from datetime import datetime, timedelta`, it's a bit clear and did remove duplicated words at all.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%m/%d/%Y` and not `%m/%d/%y`?

Comment: Can we all agree that naming a commonly-used class the same name as the module containing it is a dumb idea?  What is `datetime`?  You can't rely on convention to know, but always have to look at the imports.

Comment: Long tail legacy problem there. it "should" be `from datetime import DateTime` since classes are CamelCased, but datetime precedes PEP8.

Comment: You can also do `from datetime import datetime as DateTime, timedelta as TimeDelta`, so you have came case and yet import the module `import datetime` avoiding name conflict.

Comment: In python3, I have to do `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` and `end_date = date_1 + timedelta(days=2)`

Comment: That looks like PascalCase over camelCase

Answer (score 232):

Import `timedelta` and `date` first.

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
```

And `date.today()` will return today's datetime, which you can then add a `timedelta` to it:

```
end_date = date.today() + timedelta(days=10)
```

Comment: datetime.date.today() instead of Date.today()

Comment: @dan-klasson It doesn't work for me, `date` object don't have `timedelta` method. What Python version are you using?

Comment: @DrTyrsa My bad. Should be: `from datetime import timedelta, date; date.today() + timedelta(days=10)`

Comment: I am using python 3.7. Worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 45):

If you happen to already be using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), you can save a little space by not specifying the format:

```
import pandas as pd
startdate = "10/10/2011"
enddate = pd.to_datetime(startdate) + pd.DateOffset(days=5)
```

Comment: Worked fine for me. Thanks

Comment: just want to note that installing pandas just for this is seriously overkill.

Comment: This was the best answer for me because I was already using pandas and didn't want to import yet another library.

Answer (score 43):

This might help:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta
date1 = date(2011, 10, 10)
date2 = date1 + timedelta(days=5)
print (date2)
```

Comment: you can also do `date1 += timedelta(days=5)`.

Answer (score 19):

If you want add days to date now, you can use this code

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta


date_now_more_5_days = (datetime.now() + timedelta(days=5) ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is another method to add days on date using **dateutil's relativedelta**.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

print 'Today: ',datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S') 
date_after_month = datetime.now()+ relativedelta(days=5)
print 'After 5 Days:', date_after_month.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

> Today:  25/06/2015 15:56:09
>
> After 5 Days: 30/06/2015 15:56:09

Comment: relativedelta is especially useful when doing operations on month year etc.

Answer (score 14):

I guess you are missing something like that:

```python
from datetime import timedelta
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a function of getting from now + specified days

```
import datetime

def get_date(dateFormat="%d-%m-%Y", addDays=0):

    timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
    if (addDays!=0):
        anotherTime = timeNow + datetime.timedelta(days=addDays)
    else:
        anotherTime = timeNow

    return anotherTime.strftime(dateFormat)
```

Usage:

```
addDays = 3 #days
output_format = '%d-%m-%Y'
output = get_date(output_format, addDays)
print output
```

Comment: Good code. But your IF to test the addDays in get_date is not necessary

Answer (score 8):

In order to have have a **less verbose code**, and avoid **name conflicts** *between datetime and datetime.datetime*, you should rename the classes with **CamelCase** names.

```
from datetime import datetime as DateTime, timedelta as TimeDelta
```

So you can do the following, which I think it is clearer.

```
date_1 = DateTime.today() 
end_date = date_1 + TimeDelta(days=10)
```

Also, there would be **no name conflict** if you want to `import datetime` later on.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

#### Adding 5 days to current date.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_date = datetime.now()
end_date = current_date + timedelta(days=5) # Adding 5 days.
end_date_formatted = end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(end_date_formatted)
```

#### subtracting 5 days from current date.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

current_date = datetime.now()
end_date = current_date + timedelta(days=-5) # Subtracting 5 days.
end_date_formatted = end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(end_date_formatted)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this old thread:

I have checked but most of the answers are the same. I liked two answers from all these so I thought to check the efficiency of these two approaches.

First Approach: using the DateTime module
Second Approach: using the panda's library

So I run the test about 10k times and The pandas library method was much slower. So I suggest using the built-in DateTime module.

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import timeit

def using_datetime():
    pre_date = date(2013, 10, 10)
    day_date = pre_date + timedelta(days=5)
    return day_date

def using_pd():
    start_date = "10/10/2022"
    pd_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
    end_date = pd_date + pd.DateOffset(days=5)
    return end_date
    

for func in [using_datetime, using_pd]:
    print(f"{func.__name__} Time Took: ",  timeit.timeit(stmt=func, number=10000))
    
# Output 
# using_datetime Time Took:  0.009390000021085143
# using_pd Time Took:  2.1051381999859586
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to import `timedelta` function from `datetime`

This is how you can fix it:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

StartDate = "10/10/11"

Date = datetime.strptime(StartDate, "%m/%d/%y")

EndDate = Date.today()+timedelta(days=10)

print(EndDate)
```

This is the output from the code above: `2012-08-03 23:13:53.485750`

Answer (score 0):

using `timedelta`s you can do:

```
import datetime
today=datetime.date.today()


time=datetime.time()
print("today :",today)

# One day different .
five_day=datetime.timedelta(days=5)
print("one day :",five_day)
#output - 1 day , 00:00:00


# five day extend .
fitfthday=today+five_day
print("fitfthday",fitfthday)


# five day extend .
fitfthday=today+five_day
print("fitfthday",fitfthday)
#output - 
today : 2019-05-29
one day : 5 days, 0:00:00
fitfthday 2019-06-03
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you have'got an answer now but maybe my class I created will be also helpfull. For me it solves all my requirements I have ever had in my Pyhon projects.

```
class GetDate:
    def __init__(self, date, format="%Y-%m-%d"):
        self.tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Warsaw")

        if isinstance(date, str):
            date = datetime.strptime(date, format)

        self.date = date.astimezone(self.tz)

    def time_delta_days(self, days):
        return self.date + timedelta(days=days)

    def time_delta_hours(self, hours):
        return self.date + timedelta(hours=hours)

    def time_delta_seconds(self, seconds):
        return self.date + timedelta(seconds=seconds)

    def get_minimum_time(self):
        return datetime.combine(self.date, time.min).astimezone(self.tz)

    def get_maximum_time(self):
        return datetime.combine(self.date, time.max).astimezone(self.tz)

    def get_month_first_day(self):
        return datetime(self.date.year, self.date.month, 1).astimezone(self.tz)

    def current(self):
        return self.date

    def get_month_last_day(self):
        lastDay = calendar.monthrange(self.date.year, self.date.month)[1]
        date = datetime(self.date.year, self.date.month, lastDay)
        return datetime.combine(date, time.max).astimezone(self.tz)
```

**How to use it**

1. `self.tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Warsaw")` - here you define Time Zone you want to use in project
2. `GetDate("2019-08-08").current()` - this will convert your string date to time aware object with timezone you defined in pt 1. Default string format is `format="%Y-%m-%d"` but feel free to change it. (eg. `GetDate("2019-08-08 08:45", format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M").current()`)
3. `GetDate("2019-08-08").get_month_first_day()` returns given date (string or object) month first day
4. `GetDate("2019-08-08").get_month_last_day()` returns given date month last day
5. `GetDate("2019-08-08").minimum_time()` returns given date day start
6. `GetDate("2019-08-08").maximum_time()` returns given date day end
7. `GetDate("2019-08-08").time_delta_days({number_of_days})` returns given date + add {number of days} (you can also call: `GetDate(timezone.now()).time_delta_days(-1)` for yesterday)
8. `GetDate("2019-08-08").time_delta_haours({number_of_hours})` similar to pt 7 but working on hours
9. `GetDate("2019-08-08").time_delta_seconds({number_of_seconds})` similar to pt 7 but working on seconds

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we need to use searching by from date & to date. If we use `date__range` then we need to add 1 day to `to_date` otherwise queryset will be empty.

Example:

```
from datetime import timedelta  

from_date  = parse_date(request.POST['from_date'])

to_date    = parse_date(request.POST['to_date']) + timedelta(days=1)

attendance_list = models.DailyAttendance.objects.filter(attdate__range = [from_date, to_date])
```

Answer (score 0):

I already see a pandas example, but here a twist to it where you can directly import the Day class

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Day

date1 = datetime(2011, 10, 10)
date2 = date1 + 5 * Day()
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use it this way, It will work:**

**If you need only date, then:**

```
import datetime

StartDate = "10/10/11"
Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(StartDate, "%m/%d/%y").date()
print("Date: ", Date)

EndDate = Date + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
print("EndDate: ", EndDate)
```

**If you need date time both, then:**

```
import datetime

StartDate = "10/10/11"
Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(StartDate, "%m/%d/%y")
print("Date: ", Date)

EndDate = Date + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
print("EndDate: ", EndDate)
```

Answer (score -19):

```
class myDate:

    def __init__(self):
        self.day = 0
        self.month = 0
        self.year = 0
        ## for checking valid days month and year
        while (True):
            d = int(input("Enter The day :- "))
            if (d > 31):
                print("Plz 1 To 30 value Enter ........")
            else:
                self.day = d
                break

        while (True):
            m = int(input("Enter The Month :- "))
            if (m > 13):
                print("Plz 1 To 12 value Enter ........")
            else:
                self.month = m
                break

        while (True):
            y = int(input("Enter The Year :- "))
            if (y > 9999 and y < 0000):
                print("Plz 0000 To 9999 value Enter ........")
            else:
                self.year = y
                break
    ## method for aday ands cnttract days
    def adayDays(self, n):
        ## aday days to date day
        nd = self.day + n
        print(nd)
        ## check days subtract from date
        if nd == 0: ## check if days are 7  subtracted from 7 then,........
            if(self.year % 4 == 0):
                if(self.month == 3):
                    self.day = 29
                    self.month -= 1
                    self.year = self. year
            else:
                if(self.month == 3):
                    self.day = 28
                    self.month -= 1
                    self.year = self. year
            if  (self.month == 5) or (self.month == 7) or (self.month == 8) or (self.month == 10) or (self.month == 12):
                self.day = 30
                self.month -= 1
                self.year = self. year
                   
            elif (self.month == 2) or (self.month == 4) or (self.month == 6) or (self.month == 9) or (self.month == 11):
                self.day = 31
                self.month -= 1
                self.year = self. year

            elif(self.month == 1):
                self.month = 12
                self.year -= 1    
        ## nd == 0 if condition over
        ## after subtract days to day io goes into negative then
        elif nd < 0 :   
            n = abs(n)## return positive if no is negative
            for i in range (n,0,-1): ## 
                
                if self.day == 0:

                    if self.month == 1:
                        self.day = 30
                        
                        self.month = 12
                        self.year -= 1
                    else:
                        self.month -= 1
                        if(self.month == 1) or (self.month == 3)or (self.month == 5) or (self.month == 7) or (self.month == 8) or (self.month == 10) or (self.month ==12):
                            self.day = 30
                        elif(self.month == 4)or (self.month == 6) or (self.month == 9) or (self.month == 11):
                            self.day = 29
                        elif(self.month == 2):
                            if(self.year % 4 == 0):
                                self.day == 28
                            else:
                                self.day == 27
                else:
                    self.day -= 1

        ## enf of elif negative days
        ## adaying days to DATE
        else:
            cnt = 0
            while (True):

                if self.month == 2:  # check leap year
                    
                    if(self.year % 4 == 0):
                        if(nd > 29):
                            cnt = nd - 29
                            nd = cnt
                            self.month += 1
                        else:
                            self.day = nd
                            break
                ## if not leap year then
                    else:  
                    
                        if(nd > 28):
                            cnt = nd - 28
                            nd = cnt
                            self.month += 1
                        else:
                            self.day = nd
                            break
                ## checking month other than february month
                elif(self.month == 1) or (self.month == 3) or (self.month == 5) or (self.month == 7) or (self.month == 8) or (self.month == 10) or (self.month == 12):
                    if(nd > 31):
                        cnt = nd - 31
                        nd = cnt

                        if(self.month == 12):
                            self.month = 1
                            self.year += 1
                        else:
                            self.month += 1
                    else:
                        self.day = nd
                        break

                elif(self.month == 4) or (self.month == 6) or (self.month == 9) or (self.month == 11):
                    if(nd > 30):
                        cnt = nd - 30
                        nd = cnt
                        self.month += 1

                    else:
                        self.day = nd
                        break
                ## end of month condition
        ## end of while loop
    ## end of else condition for adaying days
    def formatDate(self,frmt):

        if(frmt == 1):
            ff=str(self.day)+"-"+str(self.month)+"-"+str(self.year)
        elif(frmt == 2):
            ff=str(self.month)+"-"+str(self.day)+"-"+str(self.year)
        elif(frmt == 3):
            ff =str(self.year),"-",str(self.month),"-",str(self.day)
        elif(frmt == 0):
            print("Thanky You.....................")
            
        else:
            print("Enter Correct Choice.......")
        print(ff)
            
            

dt = myDate()
nday = int(input("Enter No. For Aday or SUBTRACT Days :: "))
dt.adayDays(nday)
print("1 : day-month-year")
print("2 : month-day-year")
print("3 : year-month-day")
print("0 : EXIT")
frmt = int (input("Enter Your Choice :: "))
dt.formatDate(frmt)
```

Comment: There is a built-in timedelta object that takes care of everything you're trying to do here, and then some.