# Subtracting n days from date in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timedelta

I want to subtract n days from a file's timestamp, but it doesn't seem to be working. I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-5-days-to-date-in-python), and I think I'm close.

This is an excerpt from my code:

```
import os, time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def processData1( pageFile ):
    f = open(pageFile, "r")
    page = f.read()
    filedate = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(os.path.getmtime(pageFile)))
    print filedate
    end_date = filedate - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
    print end_date
```

Printing `filedate` works, so that date is read correctly from the files. It's the subtraction bit that doesn't seem to be working.

Desired output:
If `filedate` is 06/11/2013, `print end_date` should yield `06/01/2013`.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `time.strftime()` ?

Comment: The code is exactly as in the post, yes, if that's what you mean?

Comment: If yiou are getting any error, please add that to the question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you use [`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) you are actually converting a [`struct_time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) to a string.

so `filedate` is actually a string. When you try to `+` or `-` a `datetime.timedelta` from it, you would get an error. Example -

```
In [5]: s = time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y', time.gmtime(time.time()))

In [6]: s
Out[6]: '09/01/2015'

In [8]: s - datetime.timedelta(days=10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-fb1d19ed0b02> in <module>()
----> 1 s - datetime.timedelta(days=10)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

To get a similar behavior to [`time.gmtime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.gmtime) to can instead use [`datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp) , this would provide a datetime object, from which you can subtract the timedelta.

And then if the end result you want is actually a string, you can use `datetime.strftime()` to convert it to string in required format. Example -

```
import os
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def processData1( pageFile ):
    f = open(pageFile, "r")
    page = f.read()
    filedate = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(pageFile)))
    print filedate
    end_date = filedate - timedelta(days=10)
    print end_date   #end_date would be a datetime object.
    end_date_string = end_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    print end_date_string
```

Answer (score 23):

**cleaned up import**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
start = '06/11/2013'
start = datetime.strptime(start, "%m/%d/%Y") #string to date
end = start - timedelta(days=10) # date - days
print start,end
```