# python: adding any number of days to date

Tags: python, date, timedelta

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction in working with dates and timedelta.

my understanding is that to add any number (ex: 10 days) to a date, you need to convert it to a timedelta.
if that is correct, how can I add any number to a date when it is an integer?

any documentation or links would be great - thank you.

code example, my date is as follows:

```
x = 20100103 (formatted as YYYYMMDD)
```

Comment: First of all what does it mean to add a number to a date? What is "number"? Is it amount of days? Why are you using integers instead of Python's [`datetime` and `timedelta` types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)?

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-5-days-to-date-in-python)

Comment: @freakish my apologies, I have edited the original question as you are right, I want to add any number of days to a current date

Comment: RTM. https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Comment: @antonio_zeus So ok, you have to convert your date into `datetime` object and "10 days" into `timedelta` object. Then you can add them and Python takes care of all the details of datetime modification. See the documentation I've linked in my previous comment.

Comment: @freakish that's exactly what I was looking for, the breakdown on what to do to my date (convert to datetime object) and then 10 days (to timedelta object) - ty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x=20100103
x2 = int((datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x),"%Y%m%d") + datetime.timedelta(days=10)).strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

to break it down

```
x=20100103
x_as_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(x),"%Y%m%d") 
new_datetime = x_as_datetime + datetime.timedelta(days=10) #add your timedelta
x2 = new_datetime.strftime("%Y%m%d") # format it back how you want
int(x2) # if you just want an integer ...
```

Comment: this was really helpful and informative - thank you for the additional breakdown. worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
>>> today
datetime.date(2016, 6, 14)
>>> today + datetime.timedelta(days=10)
datetime.date(2016, 6, 24)
```

There's no need to convert it to a timedelta. Just use the timedelta function, if you want to add days, use days=N, for hours, `timedelta(hours=20)`

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

StartDate = "20100103"

Date = datetime.strptime(StartDate, "%Y%m%d")
EndDate = Date + timedelta(days=10)
```