# Hello! Is there a way to modify a string from user raw_input in python?

Tags: python, string, input

I am a beginner python programmer and am trying to figure out how to modify input from a user.

```
y=raw_input("Enter the date in this format 'yyyy-mm-dd'") #user enters 
x=y-2 #I know this isn't how you would do this just trying to show an example of 
#what I am attempting.
```

I am trying to set a second variable x equal whatever date the user enters minus 2 days. I am later trying to pass the second variable in a datetime format in apscheduler. Is there any way to do modify a string like this?

Comment: Many ways of doing it. 1. try reading up on https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html . 2. If you don't want to use date time, you could just split the user input based on `-` and modify the correct slot of your new list and rebuild the string.

Comment: Duplicate of a number of posts, Start from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime and end here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-5-days-to-a-date-in-python

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciate it!