# Add +1 to the day in datetime format

Tags: python

I have this script what gets me the last datetime from a database table:

```html
import MySQLdb
import datetime as dt

database = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost", user = "root", passwd = "1234", db = "meh")
cursor = database.cursor()
query_timestamp = "SELECT refuelling_date FROM `emil_touch_fuellings` ORDER BY refuelling_date DESC LIMIT 1"
cursor.execute(query_timestamp)
dblastentrytime = cursor.fetchone()
for i in dblastentrytime:
    current=i

startdate= current.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
enddate = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
cursor.close()
print startdate
```

This will output 05/10/2016, but I want to get +1 to day to get 06/10/2016. Each time I run my script I want to get my startdate var with a +1 day on date I got from my db. I'm using python.

Comment: This post should answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-5-days-to-a-date-in-python

Answer (score 0):

for adding one day to a date use:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime(2012,9,23,12,4,5)
date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

now day is 24

Comment: dblastentrytime += dt.timedelta(days=1)
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "datetime.timedelta") to tuple

Comment: this is my date format : (datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 5, 16, 57, 23),)

Comment: why do you want it to be a tuple? get the first index `dblastentrytime[0] += dt.timedelta(days=1) `