# How to have the date days later using my format?

Tags: python, date, time

the format i need is `Y-M-D`

similar to `2017-12-01`

what i've tried :

```
import datetime
import time

todaysdate = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print (todaysdate)
end_date = todaysdate+ datetime.timedelta(days=10)
print (end_date)
```

The first part should get me today's date then i add 10 date to that date and i should have to outputs 1 in str format the other in date format.

**EDIT:** i changed my code to the following :

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta,date

def next_days(days_value):
    days_from_now = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=days_value)
    return days_from_now

print(next_days(5))
```

and i got this output `2017-12-06 11:58:45.955056`
how do i get `2017-12-06` part only.

Comment: Add .date() or make a date from thestart

Comment: Can u add a full answer bellow.

Comment: Sorry but i’m on a bus on my Phone

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-5-days-to-a-date-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't import `date` and this should work:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta


def next_days(days_value):
    days_from_now = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=days_value)
    return days_from_now.date()

print(next_days(5))
```

Comment: I have used date somewhere else in the code to be able to remove date from the import i need to replace with a function that gets me todays date i have tried datetime.now.date() but it didn't work

Comment: The code I wrote will work even if you import `date`. I didn't realize you were using it elsewhere. The code `datetime.now().date()` will also work.