# How to iterate over dates in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I've got a dataframe that has a column of dates that are formatted like this:

"1/1/2016"

I would like to create a for-loop that starts from that date and goes to "1/2/2016", "1/3/2016", and so on.

I start with this Python code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
```

Which turns the date format to this: '01-01-2016'
Next:

```
start_date = '01-01-2016'
```

Finally, the for-loop:

```
for j in range (1,30)
    start_date + j...
```

But you can't add an integer to that date format, of course.
What should I do in the for-loop to just go to the next day?

Comment: pd.Timedelta check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your final outcome wants to be, but you can use `pd.date_range`:

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('01-01-2016')

for j in pd.date_range(start_date, periods=30):
    print(j)
```

Which gives you:

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00
2016-01-02 00:00:00
2016-01-03 00:00:00
2016-01-04 00:00:00
2016-01-05 00:00:00
2016-01-06 00:00:00
...
```

Comment: This and some other answers below seem to be working for me if I try them in the interpreter, or as a python script. They don't work if I use the Jupyter notebook, which is what I'm hoping to use (though I can make do without); any idea why? I'm using Jupyter on Cocalc.

Comment: I don't use Jupyter, so I'm not sure, but what is the error that comes up?

Comment: I get: "TypeError: periods must be a number, got 30" (I used your exact code line). Works fine in a script, doesn't work in Jupyter.

Comment: That is very strange... Based on the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexes/period.py), that error is supposed to show up if the argument is non-numeric, but I have no idea why you're getting it if you pass it `30`. It seems to be reading `30` as a string or something like that... Wish I could help more, but I'm stumped

Answer (score 1):

To increase the date by one day if your are pandas' lover:

```
df['dates'].iloc[0] +pd.to_timedelta(1,'d')
```

Or you can try this :

```
from datetime import timedelta
df['dates'].iloc[0] + timedelta(days=1)  #on the left side is the date you want to increase
```

You can find more infos here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871054/8433650

Answer (score 0):

By using numpy time delta either you can add day or subtract from time stamp

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('01-01-2016') +np.timedelta64(1,'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a day with `timedelta()`

```
Import datetime

for j in range (1,30):
    start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Here is a [LINK](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) to the docs for your reference