# adding ten days to datetime

Tags: python-3.x, string, datetime, text

I want to add 10 days to `s` so I try the following

```
import datetime
s= '01/11/2018'
add = s + datetime.timedelta(days = 10)
```

But I get an error

```
TypeError: must be str, not datetime.timedelta
```

so I try

```
add = s + str(datetime.timedelta(days = 10))
```

And I get

```
'01/11/201810 days, 0:00:00'
```

But this is not what I am looking for.

I would like the following output where 10 days are added to `s`

```
'01/21/2018'
```

I have also looked [Adding 5 days to a date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-5-days-to-a-date-in-python) but this doesnt seem to work for me

How do I get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `s` is a string, not a datetime. Python knows how to add a string to a string and a datetime to a timedelta, but is pretty confused about you wanting to add a string and a timedelta.

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('01/11/2018', '%m/%d/%Y') + datetime.timedelta(days = 10)
```