# Annotate data value at the end of line matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

I am trying to add data value to the end of the line of matplotlib. This is my code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
anz_df.plot(legend=True, ax=ax, figsize= (16,8))
ax.set_title("Number of confirmed cases between Australian' States vs New Zealand")
ax.set_ylabel('Number of confirmed Cases')
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
for line, name in zip(ax.lines, anz_df.columns):
    y = line.get_ydata()[-1]
    ax.annotate(name, xy=(1,y), xytext=(6,0), color=line.get_color(), 
                xycoords = ax.get_yaxis_transform(), textcoords="offset points",
                size=14, va="center")
```

This is result:
[image]

However, I want to add data value to the end of each line.

Also, which library that I can visualise data that support mouse hover like this: 
[image]

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: About hover - check Plotly.

Comment: I will look at these libraries. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add a day to the date using `timedelta(days=1)` (from `datetime` library) in the manner described here: [Adding 5 days to a date in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-5-days-to-a-date-in-python).

Thus

```
y = line.get_ydata()[-1]
x = line.get_xdata()[-1]+timedelta(days=1) # or something reasonable
ax.annotate('{:d}'.format(y), xy=(x,y)  ...
```

For hover, you can use plotly or bokeh, the latter of which is probably easier.

Comment: Hi jgf, thanks for your comment. However, I want to add data value (number of cases) to the end of each line.

Comment: @MikeB isn't the data value just `y`? So instead of `name` you can annotate `y` formatted as string? By "line" you mean the line of data, right? Not some other line.

Comment: you are right. I did change to y but some labels just overlap so I changed to Plotly . BTW, thanks you.