# Is there a function in python that could generate date 4 weeks from current date/given date?

Tags: python

Is there any function in python that can generate date for example 4 weeks from now or given date?

I've gone through documentation from datetime modeule but couldnt find any example that can support my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-days-to-a-date-in-python, `datetime.timedelta(weeks=4)`

Answer (score 1):

```
four_weeks = datetime.timedelta(days=4*7)
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
print(dt + four_weeks)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
print(today + timedelta(weeks=1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing you're looking for is [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

```
from datetime import timedelta

def add_weeks(dt, n_weeks):
    n_days = 7 * n_weeks
    return dt + timedelta(days=n_days)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python `datetime` module has a class called `datetime` which represents a date + time, an point on time line. There is another class called timedelta that represents difference between two dates (datetiems).

You can add a date with a `timedelta`.

example code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
duration = timedelta(days=28)
target = now + duration
print(target)
```