# Python Generate Dates based on N days

Tags: python, date, datetime

The below code is a list-comprehension of all possible dates between a lower and upper bound:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

d1 = date(2022,1,1)
d2 = date(2022,12,31)

dates = [d1 + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((d2-d1).days + 1)]
```

However, instead of mentioning `d2`; I want to mention the `n` number of days I want generated:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

d1 = date(2022,1,1)
n = 3

dates = []
```

`dates`:

```py
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-03
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871016/adding-days-to-a-date-in-python

Comment: `(d2-d1).days + 1)` is the number of generated days, why don't you just replace this piece by `n`??

Comment: This was an oversight. I naively assumed it was to do with `timedelta(days=x)`. Ty

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `for-loop` and generate date with `timedelta` and store it in a list.

```
>>> [d1+timedelta(days=i) for i in range(n)]
[datetime.date(2022, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2022, 1, 2),
 datetime.date(2022, 1, 3)]

>>> [(d1+timedelta(days=i)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for i in range(n)]
['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03']
```

Explanation:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

d1 = date(2022,1,1)
n = 3

dates = []
for i in range(n):
    tmp = d1 + timedelta(days=i)
    dates.append(tmp.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    
    # Or store as <class 'datetime.date'>
    # dates.append(tmp)

print(dates)
```

Output:

```
['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03']
```

Answer (score 1):

easy:

```py
from datetime import date, timedelta

N_DAYS = 30
d1 = date(2022,1,1)
d2 = d1+ timedelta(days=N_DAYS)

dates = [d1 + timedelta(days=x) for x in range((d2-d1).days + 1)]
converted_data = list(map(lambda date:date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),dates))
print(converted_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using an external library, [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) is quite simple and versatile:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = '2022-1-1'
# or 
# d1 = datetime.date(2022,1,1)
n = 3

out = pd.date_range(d1, periods=n, freq='D').strftime('%Y-%m-%d').to_list()
```

output: `['2022-01-01', '2022-01-02', '2022-01-03']`